# (! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode) in presentation

Tags: beamer, floats

I am making a presentation and I am trying to add a figure and a caption in a particular frame. But I keep getting this error in the following line

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure*}[t]
        \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{Case1.pdf}
    \end{figure*}
\end{frame}
```

when I comment out the `\begin{figure}` and `\end{figure}` the error is removed.
And if I remove the begin and end figure I am not able to add the caption below the figure.

Comment: Try with just `figure` *without* any float specification. That is, `\begin{figure} \centering \includegraphics[.]{..} \caption{...} `\end{figure}`.

Comment: or more simply just remove the `figure*` and use `\includegraphics` directly

Answer (score 3):

[`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer) supports floats, but doesn't make them float as it does not help or make sense within a presentation. So, drop the float specifier `[t]`. Additionally, the `figure*` environment is meant to used in a `twocolumn` setup that is not natively supported in `beamer`. So, use `figure` instead.

Furthermore, there is no need to use a `figure` environment if you just want to place an image. For that you can just use `\includegraphics[.]{..}`. However, if you must, you can use `figure` with a `\caption`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  % Frame with a "float" and \caption
  \frametitle{Frame title 1}
  \begin{figure}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}
    \caption{A figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  % Frame with an image and "caption"
  \frametitle{Frame title 2}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{example-image}

  A figure
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note how `beamer` doesn't print a number with the `\caption` within a `figure`. That's because it's better to repeat a figure than to refer to it much later in the presentation using a number. Consider your audience when using references and perhaps consider using `\againframe` (if needed).